# GDAX and Etherscan

Tags: etherscan, gdax

I purchased ETH on GDAX exchange. Since I am a novice to blockchain world, I wanted to look up the transaction on Etherscan. Tried entering account id, transaction id and can't find anything.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: do you can explain more?

Comment: Usually operations within an exchange are not sent to the blockchain, they are internal operations of the exchange. An exchange allows the user to extract their coins to an external account paying a fee, that operation will generate a transaction in the blockchain.

Comment: So, when I withdraw from GDAX to Coinbase wallet the transaction should take place ? or since GDAX is affiliated with Coinbase it still be "off the books" ?

Comment: @Ismael - Might be worth adding your comment as an answer to allow for the possibility of this question being done and dusted :-)

Answer (score 1):

Usually operations within an exchange are not sent to the blockchain, they are internal operations within the exchange. An exchange allows the user to extract their coins to an external account paying a fee, that operation will generate a transaction in the blockchain.

As of August 2017 both Gdax and Coinbase are part of the same group [Coinbase vs GDAX](https://themerkle.com/coinbase-vs-gdax/). So it is possible they have an arrangment if you transfer between them you do not have to pay fees, that means no transaction is generated in the blockchain.